# How do I display 3 separate windows using buttons created from lists in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm rather new to javascript and have a problem I'm unable to solve. I need to be able to open 3 separate windows with 3 different buttons created from lists in javascript. In the code below, the list makes 3 buttons that open the same window. Each button needs to open it's own different window. It needs to all be done in javascript. Thank you.

```
"use strict";


let ANIMALS = [
    ["Cat", "Cat.jpg"],
    ["Dog", "Dog.jpg"],
    ["Bird", "Bird.jpg"]
]



let windows = [];


function init() {
    createListAnimals(ANIMALS);
}


function createListAnimals(t) {
    let domitemOl = document.createElement("ol");
    let nodeText;
    let domButton;
    for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        let domItemLi = document.createElement("li");

        // Creation of the text in a <span> inside the <li>.
        let domItemSpan = document.createElement("span");
        nodeText = document.createTextNode(t[i][0]);
        domItemSpan.appendChild(nodeText);
        domItemLi.appendChild(domItemSpan)

       
        // Button to open a window displaying the image.
        domButton = document.createElement("input");
        domButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
        domButton.setAttribute("value", "Open");
        domButton.setAttribute("id", "Open_" + i)
        domButton.addEventListener("click", createWindow);
        domItemLi.appendChild(domButton);

        // Button to close the window.
        domButton = document.createElement("input");
        domButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
        domButton.setAttribute("value", "Close");
        domButton.setAttribute("id", "Close_" + i)
        domButton.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
        domItemLi.appendChild(domButton);


        // Adds the <li> inside the <ol>.
        domitemOl.appendChild(domItemLi);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(domitemOl);

    // Button to close all the windows.
    domButton = document.createElement("input");
    domButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    domButton.setAttribute("value", "Close All");
    domButton.setAttribute("id", "Close_All");
    domButton.addEventListener("click", closeWindow);
    document.body.appendChild(domButton);
}

// Function that allows to create the HTML content inside an empty window.

function loadImage(f, descriptionAnimals) {
    f.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');
    f.document.write('<html lang="eng">');
    f.document.write('  <head>');
    f.document.write('      <title>Animal - ' + descriptionAnimals[f.name][0] + '</title>');
    f.document.write('      <style>');
    f.document.write('          img { width: 600px; height: 400px; }');
    f.document.write('      </style>');
    f.document.write('  </head>');
    f.document.write('  <body>');
    f.document.write('      <p><img src="img/' + descriptionAnimals[f.name][1] + '" alt="' + descriptionAnimals[f.name][0] + '" /></p>"');
    f.document.write('  </body>');
    f.document.write('</html>');
}


//      the attribute "name" of the windows already created.
function existingWindows(windows, nameWindow) {
    
    for (let i in windows) {
        if (windows[i].domWindow.name === nameWindow)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `domButton.addEventListener("click", createWindow);` <--- may we please see the `createWindow` method.

Comment: Currently nothing in the `createWindow` method since I'm not sure how to code the buttons and this method would require the buttons coded already(from the extent of my knowledge, which isn't all that much). Sorry for the bother. `function createWindow(ev) { }` is everything that's in the method.